# Why does Rust allow multidefinition of identifiers?

Tags: rust

Consider a mini example

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = Vec::from([1, 2, 3]);
    let Vec = 1.;
    println!("{}", Vec);
    let b = Vec::from([1, 2, 3]);
    let c: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
}
```

where I redefine `Vec` as a `f64` variable. Why does Rust allow for such operation?

The code above will print `1.` and suprisingly after redefining `Vec` as a number, the lines `let b = Vec::new();` work as well! So `Vec` exists both as an `f64` and a `Vec struct`? In many other languages, I think they will throw errors.

Suppose that both `f64` and `Vec` have a method `test()` implemented, if I call `Vec.test()`, does it excute `test()` from `f64` or `Vec`?

Comment: They are syntactically separate, so it's allowed. While that's slightly unusual, it's not completely unheard of - for example, [this valid java code](https://pastebin.com/RBYMabvv) has method and local variable named `hello` coexisting just fine.

Comment: @user4815162342 well, suppose that both `f64` and `Vec` have a method `test()`, if I call `Vec.test()`, does it excute test() from `f64` or `Vec`?

Comment: `Vec` as type and `Vec` as value (of type `f64`) are completely different things. To call the `Vec` method on the `Vec` type you'd have to call `Vec::test(...)`, and for the `f64` method you'd have to call `Vec.test(...)` or `f64::test(&Vec)` - no ambiguity either way. (Assuming the `f64` method takes `&self` - and if it didn't, you couldn't even invoke it through instance so there'd be even less confusion.)

Comment: @user4815162342 ah yes, thanks, I forgot the different between `::` and `.`.

Comment: See https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/names/namespaces.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Types and variables are distinguished by syntax, so using the same identifier for both is harmless and therefore allowed. While that's slightly unusual, it's not unheard of - for example, this is valid Java:

```java
public class HelloWorld {
     public static void main(String []args) {
        int hello = 1;
        hello(hello); // <-- wat
     }
     static void hello(int n) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + n);
     }
}
```

Note that such use of identifier will inevitably trigger a compilation warning because variables and types use different case conventions.

> Suppose that both `f64` and `Vec` have a method `test()` implemented, if I call `Vec.test()`, does it execute `test()` from `f64` or `Vec`?

It executes the one from `f64`.

There is no ambiguity because `Vec` as type and `Vec` as value of type `f64` are completely different things. To call the method defined by the `Vec` type through the `Vec` type, you'd have to call `Vec::test(...)`. To call the `f64` method through the `Vec` variable you'd have to call `Vec.test(...)` or `f64::test(&Vec, ...)` - no ambiguity either way. (And that's assuming `f64::test()` takes `&self`; if it didn't, you couldn't invoke it through instance in the first place, so there'd be even less confusion.)